# Use same XAML files in multiple projects

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, architecture

I have four similar apps with different branding.

```
App
\ Views
  \ MainPage.xaml
  \ LoginPage.xaml
  \ YourAccountPage.xaml
  \ TodoListPage.xaml
  \ TodoDetailsPage.xaml
  \ TodoItemView.xaml
\ Images
  \ App1_logo.png
```

I want to make my projects easier to manage. When I make one change I must usually have 4 instances of Visual Studio up and do the same change in all projects, or risk forgetting it.

I do API calls and display data in `.xaml.cs` files.

I have already separate projects for models and service implementation. But it's not straightforward with XAML files.

Comment: If you could specify on what changes between your different brandings I might be able to make my answer a bit more concrete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are giving very little information on the context of your application. Since you are using XAML I'm assuming you intend to use MVVM.

I think your problem is that you call data and do API calls in code behind (xaml.cs). Aggregating data to display is what a view model is for.
You should design your view with the thought in mind that the data you need will be provided for you by the view model (it does not matter how yet). If need be, imagine that you told some other developer exactly what kind of data you need, i.e. a list, sorted by timestamp. How that other dev aggregates that data is not your concern.

Avoid doing logic in the view as this will cause a coupling of your business logic with your view which will lead to exactly the problem you have right now.

Once your view is decoupled from the logic you could make a library with just the views.